# Can I set PhpStorm up to utilize an application's GLOBAL vars?

Tags: php, global-variables, phpstorm

I am trying to gain a better understanding of PHPStorm and was wondering if it is able to utilize another application's global variables.

For instance, if I am writing an addon for a CMS, can I run the script in the console to see the results instead of launching it in the web browser and use the CMS GLOBAL VARS like `require_once PATH_THIRD . 'my_folder/my_file.php';`? Where `PATH_THIRD`is set by the CMS and kept in the DB.

I have the database established and connected via IDE datasource.

I have all of the CMS files in the project.

Comment: Not in such case for sure -- PhpStorm does not read values from DB for such substitutions. You could write a plugin specifically for that CMS .. then maybe (why not) .. but PhpStorm itself or any standard CMS/Framework support plugins do not support this. I personally would disable any inspection that checks path inclusion -- it's way too dynamic and unpredictable to be analysed properly by generic static analysis that IDE performs.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So for any requirements, during development, would you just suggest hard coded paths?

Comment: Why hard coding? It most likely will cause some issues when deployed to production/copied to another server. Just do what your CMS tells you (it surely should have some "best practices"). If `require_once PATH_THIRD . 'my_folder/my_file.php';` is the way how it officially suggested ... then use it. It just that I would ignore (even disable) any inspections in this *particular* regard.

Comment: hmmm... Since I need the variables being pulled into that file from the required statement in order to debug, I thought I would need to hard code them.